# Adding delay in observable returns partial data in Angular rxjs

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

In my code I need to add delay by using **timer(500)**. But the issue is that it returns partial data. It is returning 2 fields while actual data has 17 fields. I have attached my code. please see it. Thank you

**Returned value:**

```
 ['booking_display_id', 'edit']
```

**Expected value:**

```
 ['booking_display_id', 'bookingstatus', 'b_contactname', 'member', 'b_emailaddress', 'b_mobilenumber', 'startdate', 'enddate', 'duration', 'bookingguest', 'guestnotes', 'vouchers', 'paypalpaymentpdt', 'totalCost', 'canPay', 'canCancel', 'edit']
```

```js
 this.displayedColumns = combineLatest(this.table.columns.reduce((observables: Observable<boolean>[], col) => {
  // handle showIf property of column
  const show = col.showIf(this.injector, this.route.queryParamMap);
  observables.push(show instanceof Observable ? show : of(show));
  return observables;
}, []), timer(500)).pipe(
  map(showCols => {
    const cols = this.table.columns.filter((c, i) => showCols[i])
      .map(c => c.id);
    this.editEnabled && cols.push('edit');
    this.deleteEnabled && cols.push('delete');
    console.log('cols', cols)
    return cols;
  })
 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you pass an array of observables as well as another observable to the combineLatest. However it only takes an array of observables (1dimensional array). Therefor you need to either wrap your reduce with another `combineLatest` or spread them ( => `[...obs, timer]` obs would be your reduce) into one array.

This is your simplified current call

```js
combineLatest([
    [of(1), of(2), of(3)],
    timer(500)
]);
```

---

I would recommend you use the spread operator to build a new array like so or you can use another `combineLatest` since it is another array of observables.

---

Also I recommend that you use `delay` instead of `timer` (delay runs only once)

If you want your values to be separated from the timer
`combineLatest([combineLatest(..obs), timer])`

```js
combineLatest([
    combineLatest([of(1), of(2), of(3)]),
    timer(500)
]).pipe(
    map(([yourValues, timer]) => {
        // ...
    })
)
```

If you do not want your values to be separated from the timer
`combineLatest([..obs, timer])`

```js
combineLatest([
    ...[of(1), of(2), of(3)],
    timer(500)
]).pipe(
    map(([yourValuesWithTimer]) => {
        // ...
    })
)
```